# Is Union supported in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to add two table using UNION ALL keyword.

I see lot of forum that hibernate is not supporting union all .

Is this still a bug or its solved in latest version .

Comment: I would not go that far to call a missing feature in a piece of software a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, but I am working on it for Hibernate 6.0. In the meantime you could use [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start), a query builder library that works on top of JPA, which has support for this. See the [documentation](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#normal-set-operations) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can write [polymorphic query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-polymorphism). Under the hood hibernate will use `UNION`. See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class) section of documentation.